# Legacy stored procedure not running in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

I am in the process of moving a SQL Server 2000 database to a SQL Server 2008 R2 platform.

However there is a problem in the sense that 1 stored procedure seems not to run in SQL Server 2008.

This the stored procedure

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[prAccntDetails] 
  @budgetId nvarchar(4) = NULL,
  @taskId nvarchar(10) = NULL,
  @grantId nvarchar(13) = NULL,
  @locId nvarchar(13) = NULL,
 @accntId nvarchar(15)
AS
IF @budgetId IS NULL SET @budgetId = '%'
IF @taskId IS NULL SET @taskId = '%'
IF @grantId IS NULL SET @grantId = '%'
IF @locId IS NULL SET @locId = '%'
SELECT d.accntId, d.actualAmt, d.commAmt,d.date, d.jnlType, 
    d.jnlSource, o.emailAddress, d.transReff, d.descriptn
FROM tblOperators o INNER JOIN
    tblAllDetails d ON 
    o.operatorId = d.jnlSource
WHERE d.budgetId LIKE @budgetId
AND RTRIM(d.taskId) LIKE @taskId
AND RTRIM(d.grantId) LIKE @grantId
AND RTRIM(d.locId) LIKE @locId
AND RTRIM(d.accntId) LIKE @accntId 
ORDER BY  d.date
```

In SQL Server 2000, the procedure runs okay when I supply the necessary parameters but in SQL Server 2008 it returns nothing. All help will be appreciated

Comment: I don't think we have enough information. Are you sure the old and new databases are identical? Did you do an in-place upgrade? Do you have a backup copy of the original database that you can try restoring to a new database and trying again? Also, "it returns nothing" is not clear. Do you get a rowset with 0 rows, or nothing at all, or an error? Have you queried the `tblAllDetails` table one bit at a time to see if it is ok? What is calling the stored procedure  and how are you verifying that it is being given the same parameters as before? There is a lot to tell us before we can help you.

Comment: Did you copy data from sql 2000 table to 2008 table? You might be running procedure on different set of data for same parameters. you may want to change the query to do `(@budgetId is null or d.budgetId = @budgetId)` instead of setting them to `'%'` and using `LIKE`

Comment: seems like you're just missing the data